# Is my understanding with integration correct here?

Tags: calculus, integration, differential-geometry

Let’s say $y = F(x)+c$.

If I take $\frac{d}{dx} (F(x)+c )=f(x)$, we get
$$d(F(x)+c))=f(x)dx $$

Now what I got to understand from my textbook is that

$d(F(x)+c)) = dy$, i.e. when we take the slope of small quantity of $y$ with $x$, then that rate of change of $y$ w.r.t.  $x$ is $dy$.

On the other hand , $f(x)$ is the slope that you got $\frac{dy}{dx} $

So can I say $\frac{dy}{dx} dx= dy$ ?

Q is also that what is meant by $\frac{dy}{dx} dx $  if I want to imagine it.

Comment: [See my article on taylor series](https://brianbabu890.medium.com/)

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of the differentials,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x)$$ where $dx$ is a nonzero variable.

Hence

$$\frac{dy}{dx}dx=dy$$ holds as with any fraction.